# Can't instantiate variable properly

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, static, final

I am trying to create a variable to get an email from a form but i can't have it without doube double quote.

When I write `public static String CHAMP_PASS="password";`  everything's right
but the second line is `public static String CHAMP_EMAIL="email";` and the value of CHAMP_EMAIL is "email and not just email ....

Here is my total code

```
package com.isep.connexion.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.isep.eleve.model.Eleve;
import com.isep.metier.Users;

public final class ConnexionForm {
    private static final String CHAMP_EMAIL = "email";// value : "email"
    private static final String CHAMP_PASS   = "password";  // value : password
// i've tried create another static final but the result is the same : "" everywhere
    private String              resultat;
    private Map<String, String> erreurs      = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getResultat() {
        return resultat;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErreurs() {
        return erreurs;
    }

    public Users connecterUser( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        /* Récupération des champs du formulaire */
        String email = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_EMAIL );
        String password = getValeurChamp( request, CHAMP_PASS );

        Users eleve = new Users();

        /* Validation du champ email. */
        try {
            validationEmail(email);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setErreur( CHAMP_EMAIL, e.getMessage() );
        }
        eleve.setEmail(email);

        /* Validation du champ mot de passe. */
        try {
            validationMotDePasse(password);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setErreur( CHAMP_PASS, e.getMessage() );
        }
        eleve.setPassword(password);

        /* Initialisation du résultat global de la validation. */
        if ( erreurs.isEmpty() ) {
            resultat = "Succès de la connexion.";
        } else {
            resultat = "Échec de la connexion.";
        }

        return eleve;
    }

    /**
     * Valide l'adresse email saisie.
     */
    private void validationEmail( String email ) throws Exception {
         if ( email != null ) {
                if ( !email.matches( "([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)" ) ) {
                    throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir une adresse mail valide." );
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir une adresse mail." );
            }
    }

    /**
     * Valide le mot de passe saisi.
     */
    private void validationMotDePasse( String password ) throws Exception {
        if ( password != null ) {
            if ( password.length() < 3 ) {
                throw new Exception( "Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 3 caractères." );
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception( "Merci de saisir votre mot de passe." );
        }
    }

    /*
     * Ajoute un message correspondant au champ spécifié à la map des erreurs.
     */
    private void setErreur( String champ, String message ) {
        erreurs.put( champ, message );
    }

    /*
     * Méthode utilitaire qui retourne null si un champ est vide, et son contenu
     * sinon.
     */
    private static String getValeurChamp( HttpServletRequest request, String nomChamp ) {
        String valeur = request.getParameter( nomChamp );
        if ( valeur == null || valeur.trim().length() == 0 ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return valeur;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the controller part

```
package com.isep.connexion.controlleur;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.isep.connexion.model.ConnexionForm;
import com.isep.eleve.model.Eleve;
import com.isep.metier.Demo;
import com.isep.metier.Users;


 // Servlet implementation class Connexion

@WebServlet("/Connexion")
public class ConnexionController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String ATT_USER = "eleve";
    public static final String ATT_FORM = "form";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_USER = "sessionUser";
    public static final String LOGIN = "/view/connex.jsp";
    public static final String ETUDIANT = "/view/AccueilEtudiant.jsp";
    public static final String TUTEUR = "/view/ProfilTuteur.jsp";



     // @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()

    public ConnexionController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


     // @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, //HttpServletResponse response)

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

//      Diriger vers la jsp
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(LOGIN).forward( request, response );
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ConnexionForm form = new ConnexionForm();
        Users eleve = form.connecterUser( request );
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        request.setAttribute( ATT_FORM, form );
        request.setAttribute( ATT_USER, eleve );

        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() && eleve.getPassword().equals(demo.chargerMDP(eleve.getEmail())) ) {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, eleve );
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( ETUDIANT ).forward( request, response );
        } else {

            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( LOGIN ).forward( request, response );
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, null );
        }



        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() ) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my JSP code :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GAPP/ressources/css/lastcss.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Gestion APP</title>
</head>
<body class="connexion">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modal-md">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="text-center ">Connexion</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="col-md-12 center-block" method="post"
                    action="connexion">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                            value="<c:out value="${param.email}"/>"
                            class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="email" required
                            autofocus /><br> <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['email']}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password"
                            class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="password" required /><br>
                        <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['password']}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success"
                            value="login"><br>
                        <p class="${empty form.erreurs ? 'succes' : 'erreur'}">${form.resultat}</p>
                        <p>${sessionScope.sessionUser.email}</p> <!-- pour voir que la session est détruite -->
                        <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span> <span><a
                            href="#">Mot de passe oublié</a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you trying escape the double quote, like "\""?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, or what code it's related to.

Comment: If you want your variable to be "email" nad not only email (without quote), you need to initialise your variable correctly.

Comment: @Mayeul sgc : You can initialise as     `public static String CHAMP_PASS="\"password\"";`

Comment: i don't want to have the quotes, my CHAMP_PASS is getting the password right from the form but i can't achieve to get the email and i think this variable may be the cause, so i want to have my variable CHAMP_EMAIL without doube quot when initialized

Comment: It doesn't have a double-quote.

Comment: Not it hasn't in the code but when i check my variable value, as you see CHAMP_PASS and CHAMP_EMAIL should have the same semantic, but it doesn't, the CHAMP_PASS value is : password et CHAMP_EMAIL is : "email", so when it appears in the eclipse window i have "password" and ""email"" as values ....